# Implementing CSS in android webview

Tags: android, css, webview

I m trying to create book reader(EPUB) so i want to display the book page in 2 page(Horizontally) like normal book, i create two `webview`(runtime) and try to maintain the content of it. for next and previous i just use 
webview's

```
webViewRead.scrollBy(0, 0);
webViewRead.scrollTo(0, postion);
```

but it was to difficult for me to maintain all TOC in next and previous. So is it possible to use One view and divide the content using CSS ?

Like:

```
webkit-column-count: 
moz-column-gap: 
webkit-column-gap:
```

is batter option ?
my html pages is already in SDCARD then how to attach new css file to those html files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use WebView.loadData method instead of loadurl or file.

Runtime generate or get data content from html file and add css content in data then after load this data on webview....

i think this way you can add css contet in your existing html file data and display in webview...

Thanks